# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}\cap(-10, 10)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $\mathbb{Z}\cap(-10, 10)$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Pick any $x\in\{x_i\}_{i=-9}^9$, define $\varepsilon :=10-|x|$. Then pick $y\in B_\varepsilon(x)$ so that $|y-x|<\varepsilon$. We need to show that $|y|<10$. Now, $|y|=|y-x+x|\le |y-x|+|x|<\varepsilon+|x|=10-|x|+|x|=10$.

Do you think this proof is correct?

Comment: No, as $\mathbb{Z}\cap(-10, 10)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. In your "proof", to show that the set is open you also need to show that $y\in \Bbb Z$, and... in general you can't.

Comment: Can we say this ball isn't closed either?

Comment: Which ball? $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$? We could, but that seems irrelevant. $\Bbb Z \cap(-10, 10)$ is closed in $\Bbb R$ (why?).

Comment: Sorry, not the ball, but the set. Is the complement of this set open? If so, then I don't quite see how, since the end-points $\{-10\}$ and $\{10\}$ are not included in $\mathbb{Z}\cap (-10,10)$. Also it's not completely clear to me if the complement is a set of only integers or also other reals.

Comment: The set is closed in $\Bbb R$, thus its complement **in $\Bbb R$** is open. Singletons (one-element sets) are closed in $\Bbb R$, and finite unions of closed sets are closed. The set has 19 elements. How could its complement *in $\Bbb R$* possibly contain only integers? You seem very confused about basic concepts.

Comment: Yes, the $\mathbb{Z}$ part has been confusing me, but now things are getting clearer. Obviously, I need to pay more attention to the fact that the set is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Now I realized that the set is basically $[-9, 9]=(10,10)$ with integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've proven $(-10,10)$ is open by showing that for any $x\in (-10,10)$ the ball $B_{10-|x|}(x)$ is contained in the set. Or, rather, you've shown that around each point in $\mathbb Z \cap (-10,10)$, there is an open ball contained in $(-10,10)$. The problem is that this isn't what you need to prove to show openness - you'd need to show that, around each point in $\mathbb Z \cap (-10,10)$ there is an open ball contained in $\mathbb Z\cap (-10,10)$. In particular, you'd need to additionally show that the $y$ in your proof is an integer.

(This is problematic because in *every* open ball, there is a non-integer, meaning the set is actually not open, nor is any non-empty subset of $\mathbb Z$)

Comment: Can't an open ball be "discrete", containing only integers?

Comment: @sequence No. What's your definition of "open ball"? Mine is $B_{\varepsilon}(x)=\{y\in\mathbb R:|x-y|<\varepsilon\}$ which doesn't admit any sets of only integers.

Answer (score 3):

No, your definition of an open set is not correct. Given any point in the set, you need to be able to find an $\epsilon$ so that the whole $\epsilon$ ball around the point is in your set. $0$ is in your set. What ball centered on $0$ is also in your set?

Comment: I can't say *exactly*, but it's very small!

Comment: All balls spanning $\{-i, i\}$ for $i=9,8,..,1$ are in the set, I think.

Comment: No, a $1/4$ ball includes the point $1/8$, which is not in your set because it is not in $\Bbb Z$

Comment: Can't an open ball be "discrete", containing only integers? Looks like it's a matter of definition, and I didn't know such details.

Comment: @sequence it depends on which topology do you define on $\mathbb R$ if you take the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ which say that an open set is a union of open intervals. then no.

Comment: If you take the discrete metric, then open sets can be closed at the same time.

Comment: If you talk about the reals and want to use some other topology than the standard one, you need to say that.  People will assume the usual topology otherwise. There certainly are many others.

Answer (score 1):

You don't just need to show that $|y|<10$ which implies $y\in(-10,10)$, you also need to show that $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $y\in\mathbb{Z}\cap(-10,10)$ holds (which is not the case).

Answer (score 1):

The complement of the set $\mathbb{Z}\cap (-10,10)=\{-9,\ldots,9\}$ is a union of open sets and so is itself open. A set is closed if its complement is open.
Edit: assuming "standard topology", i.e. not a space with the discrete metric.